# run UNIX programs from the working directory?

Tags: macos, bash, unix

In order to run UNIX programs from my current directory, I included this in my `~/.profile` (I'm using Mac OS 10.9):

```
export PATH="./:$PATH"
```

Anything wrong with this approach?  It seems obvious, so why isn't it included by default?  And, is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/156582/why-is-not-in-the-path-by-default

Comment: And http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65700/11750

Comment: Apart from the security risks, one of the most common names for a small test program is `test`. You don't want to have executables in your current directory hiding standard commands. Just get into the habit of typing `./` in front of any local commands. Among other things, the `./` is a reminder that executing a command in the current directory is different from executing some standard command in `/bin`.

Comment: Duplicate questions from other SE sites, but not SO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don't do it.**

Adding `.` to `$PATH` is a security risk, that's why it's not like that by default. Consider the paths listed in `$PATH` as "trusted locations". You can run the programs and scripts in them without typing their absolute paths.

If you add `.` to `$PATH`, then you may run things by accident. For example I often run the `netstat` command to check statistics. I'm so used to it, I type only until "nets" and press tab, and I know it will be auto-completed to "netstat" so I very quickly press enter. If I had `.` on my `$PATH`, and there was a malicious script named "netst" in the current directory, then I might accidentally run it when I mean to run `netstat` as usual, pressing enter too fast to realize that tab auto-completed to `netst` instead of `netstat`.

This is just one example, I could easily think of more. Having `.` on `$PATH` is a security risk, that's why it's never there by default in any system. Appending `.` to the end is better than prepending it, but it's really best to not do it at all. Typing the `./` in front of programs should not be too much of a hassle, and you have the peace of mind of knowing exactly what you're running.

I think the conclusions in the duplicate questions are too soft:

- https://superuser.com/questions/156582/why-is-not-in-the-path-by-default
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65700/is-it-safe-to-add-to-my-path-how-come

Nobody should ever do this. The convenience this gives is ridiculously small compared to the dangers.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is exactly the answer I was looking for.  I will remove it from my $PATH.

Answer (score 1):

That's a good way to do it if you need it.

One reason it's not included by default is that malicious packages (of any kind, like tgz) can contains programs named the same as system commands that will remove things, start viruses or small daemons for future DDoS attacks.

What if a pack contains a program called `emacs` or `vi`? That besides showing the directory or change working directory also does something else?

So before putting that in your path consider what you will download.

Personally I'm happy with running `./local_program` instead of putting it on the path.

Comment: _What if a pack contains a program called `ls` or `cd`?_ this is easily overcome by _appending_ `.` to `PATH`.

Comment: builtins will not get confused with commands, unless they have been specifically `enable -n`. So in fact, `cd` will always be the builtin, regardless it's in the `PATH` or not, unless it has been `enable -n cd`. Technically, your sentence is not 100% accurate regarding this fact.

Comment: Right, so built-ins was a bad example but it's true for a lot of other programs. I'll change my answer to say `emacs` and `vi` instead.

Comment: "That's a good way to do it" -- No, it's very *bad* way to do it, because of the security hole it opens. What if you `cd` to some directory that contains a malicious program named `ls`?

Answer (score 1):

The dangers of putting `.` in your `$PATH` are easy to find in other SO answers, so I'll just concentrate on "is there a better way to do [it]?". If "[it]" is "run my scripts without annoying punctuation," then the better way is to put all of your scripts in a directory called, for example, `~/bin`, and add that to your `$PATH`.

You still need to be careful about what you put into that directory, and you will still have to avoid reusing names of built-ins as executables (`test` and `time` are popular bad names), but it doesn't open you up to random exploits or unexpected consequences of typing `ls` from the wrong directory.