# executable file doesn't print anything

Tags: bash, unix

I've written a simple script, that basically looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Hello World
```

I'm trying to run this in my unix terminal but it basically does nothing. no errors, no printing, nothing

```
[solgag@t2 ~]$ olga
[solgag@t2 ~]$
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Try `./test` instead. If you run just `test`, bash will look for an executable named `test` in `$PATH` and it will find it (or maybe execute its own built-in?) as `test` is a standard command in UNIX.

Comment: ok, I changed the name to olga. tried ./olga, got an error: -bash: ./olga: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory .
I have to mention that I'm not supposed to use ./, just olga

Comment: What's the output of `which bash`? (Or try replacing `/bin/bash` with `/usr/bin/env bash`) If it's supposed to be just `olga`, then you need to copy the script into some directory which is in your `$PATH` variable or add the current location of the script to your `$PATH`.

Comment: the output is "/bin/bash" and I've added "PATH=$PATH:." to the bashrc file.

Comment: Oh I see :) The `^M` is a Windows line ending. You need to save the script with LF line endings instead of CRLF. Alternatively, you can run `dos2unix olga` to convert the endings.

Comment: Ok, you can use tr instead: `tr -d '\r' < olga > olga_unix && mv olga_unix olga`

Comment: ok, ./olga works. but just olga doesnt. still command not found

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43887/discussion-between-ales-t-and-littlerunaway)

Comment: Please do not add `.` to your `PATH`. Move your script to `~/bin` and add `~/bin` in your `PATH` and then `olga` will work. See my answer to this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021603/run-unix-programs-from-the-working-directory/20021932#20021932

Answer (score 0):

if you shell script name is `olga` you need to run in terminal as

```
$./olga
```

To run the script as specified above you need to have executable permissions you can add executable permission using `chmod` command

```
$chmod u+x ./olga
```

You can also run a bash script using `sh` command

```
$sh olga
```